# How to phrase follow-up email to professor to find out whether funding has come through regarding potential graduate school project?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, funding, email, research-assistantship

I am attempting to find a researcher to work with for graduate school. Fortunately I found one with very similar interests to mine. I have been in contact with him since August, where I spoke with him over the phone. He said, unfortunately, he does not have a project that I could work on (that is in my interest) at the moment, but he is waiting to hear back from a funding comittee. He told me to email him to check in again in October. I did and we exchanged a few emails, where he said that he had still not heard back and for me to check in again mid-November. I am about to email him again.

My question is: **how should I phrase what I say in the email so as to not sound "greedy"?**

(i.e., I do not want to say something that sounds like "hey did you find out about the research project yet?"). I know I have emailed him about this before, but I feel like my email came off as that the first time. Plus, I do not want to copy and paste what I sent him last time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overthink it, he did ask you to email him. Keep your email short (one or two lines). Wait until mid-end November and reply to the previous email with something like "Hi Dr. Lastname, I'm still interested in the ___ project and just wanted to follow up with your previous email from October to see if you have any update about the research project and funding. Regards, aspire94"